# How to make and apply (patch) one side diff?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, configuration, diff, patch

I want to make a shell script that updates a config file.

The file present on the server has information, like various IP addresses.

The new file has more code, from new configs added to the system, I want to be able to add these new configurations to the server file without changing what's already configured there

**example:**

**server file**

```
[config]
ip=127.0.0.1
port=22
```

**new file**

```
[config]
ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
port=XX
user=root
```

I want the resulting file to be

```
[config]
ip=127.0.0.1
port=22
user=root
```

How would be a good way to do that? I don't want to rely on line position and such, because the actual config files are quite large and more lines could have been added to the server file.

I've tried to make a diff from the files and apply the patch, but it didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This may require some config-file-specific logic. It might be worth investigating a framework such as [ucf](https://launchpad.net/ucf).

Answer (score 7):

As Gilles says, you'll need to use a tool that knows about the format of your config files.  For your particular example, you can use a short Python script that uses the built-in [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module.

- First, let's say your original configuration file on the server is `original.cfg`:

  ```
  [config]
  ip=127.0.0.1
  port=22
  ```
- Now put your changes in a new file called `update.cfg`:

  ```
  [config]
  user=root
  ```

  This file should have new or changed entries listed under the section heading where you would like them to go.
- Then run a script like this one:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ConfigParser

  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

  # Read the original config file
  with open('original.cfg', 'r') as f:
      config.readfp(f)

  # Also read in all the changes we'd like to make
  with open('update.cfg', 'r') as f:
      config.readfp(f)

  # Write the full new config file out
  with open('output.cfg', 'w') as f:
      config.write(f)
  ```

There are, of course, plenty of variations on how to do this.  For example, the config changes could be coded directly into the Python script rather than read from a separate `update.cfg` file.  This should give you a good base to get started, though.

Answer (score 4):

Parse them into two separate datasets with whatever program you prefer. I would use common lisp and store each config file as a nested list of lists.

And then use language tools to do the merging/patching/union/set-difference/etc. At a high level, for a one side diff, the code might look like:

```
(union
  (vals A :keys 'all)
  (vals B
    :keys  
    (set-difference
      (keys B)
      (keys A))))
```

And then write out the resulting dataset to a file.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have example CL code?

Comment: Not anything that will compile, other than the sketch above. I figured if you went this route, you wouldn't use common lisp, so I wanted to just convey the idea.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, I'm not the OP, and do know CL, so I'm interested. I see there is something like py-configparser, which might be able to do similar things to the configparser module.

Comment: Yeah; the python solutions here are much more practical. But if you can get to the point in python where you are expressing set-diff, union, intersection, etc., then I think you have a more general case of this problem solved. Which might be useful.

Comment: Ah; you said you do know CL; yeah there are XML parser packages; I've messed around with Closure XML, but this config isn't XML. I've found JSON parsers for CL, but this config isn't JSON either. I dunno' if there's a lisp package to parse this one. I'd have to do a bit of research; and if not, I'd just use python :)

Comment: Oh, and you found one; wow; this just might be possible. If it ends up as a weekend project, I'll make sure to post actual code that compiles.

Comment: Actually, I think CL is quite well suited to the task of parsing data - it's probably better than Python. It is just that, as in many other cases, nobody actually uses it for that. :-) CL is just a strangely underused language.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) Python library for this. If you do this, it does require writing Python to interface with the config files. I typically have a `default_conf` file which has default values, and I can selectively override these settings with some other file, say `user_conf`

Here is the code I am currently using as an example. The second half of the function is validation, which is important, but you can ignore it to a first approximation. For usage you do

```
conf = get_conf()
ip = conf["ip"]
```

In your case, I guess the server file is the one that overrides, though more usually it is the user file which overrides the system file. That is certainly the user convention in Unix-type systems.

To write a ConfigObj object to file, to a first approximation you do (if `config` is your object as in the script below)

```
config.filename = filename
config.write()
```

So you could modify the function below to write to a file instead of returning the config object if you want. See [Writing a Config File](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#writing-a-config-file) for a little more detail.

```
def get_conf():
    import configobj, validate, sys
    try:
        config = configobj.ConfigObj('default_conf', configspec='conf.validate', raise_errors=True)
    except configobj.ConfigObjError:
        print "ERROR FOR CONFIG FILE 'default_conf':"
        raise
    try:
        user = configobj.ConfigObj('user_conf', configspec='conf.validate', raise_errors=True)
    except configobj.ConfigObjError:
        print "ERROR FOR CONFIG FILE 'user_conf':"
        raise
    config.merge(user)

    #This is config file validation
    fdict = {'check_list_of_list_of_integers': list_of_list_of_integers}
    validator = validate.Validator(fdict)

    results = config.validate(validator, preserve_errors=True)
    if results != True:
        for entry in configobj.flatten_errors(config, results):
            # each entry is a tuple
            section_list, key, error = entry
            if key is not None:
                section_list.append(key)
            else:
                section_list.append('[missing section]')
            section_string = ', '.join(section_list)
            if error == False:
                error = 'Missing value or section.'
            print section_string, ' = ', error

        sys.exit(1)

    return config
```

UPDATE 16th December 2015: Something like YAML is probably a better general solution. I recommend that instead of ConfigObj. For one thing,
it's more flexible.